# Adding a SUM row to a query in google sheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have a Google Sheet and I want to use a Query to dynamically use some data and calculate the sum from some particular columns. I can collect the data well. Then when I want to add the SUM of the columns I have an error. Below is the code is used:

```
={QUERY(data;"SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G ORDER BY E DESC";1);{
    "TOTAL";
    SUM('Données'!$E$1:$E)
  }}
```

Can you help me? I would like to have the sum of columns D,E,F at the last line.

THank you

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @player0 here is a link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CU8wHd9IxfpKyuRZAPylIYxwWQBRNKf52qwsyixczMw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: It's not anymore private

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
={QUERY(data; "select A,B,C,D,E,F,G where A is not null order by E desc"; 1);
 "Total"\""\SUM(Données!C2:C)\SUM(Données!D2:D)\SUM(Données!E2:E)\""\""}
```

Comment: The table appears but there is not Total line appearing.

Comment: I found I have a problem with the named range. I selected all the sheets, when I select only the row with values it works well. Is there a way to dynamically extend the named range?

Answer (score 0):

The array sizes are different so you cannot group without "appending" the missing columns.

```
={QUERY(data,"SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G ORDER BY E DESC",1);{
    "TOTAL",,
    SUM('Données'!$C$1:$C),
    SUM('Données'!$D$1:$D),
    SUM('Données'!$E$1:$E),,
  }}
```

Comment: I have an error using that formula. Nothing is rendered. I noticed for some formulas, I must use ; instead of ,